# VS Code for Python entering a new line when function call is long

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a long time problem and it got me angry, so I will ask here. When I have a long function call in VS Code, it automatically enteres a new line somewhere in the parametres.

I have this on one line:

```
dict_file = os.path.join(path_converted, 
    'dictionary_'+filename+'.picklelongtestlongtestlongtestlongtestlongtest')
```

and it adds newLine behind `"(path_converted, 'dictionary_' +"` and the rest is written on the new line with some indention.

I have pretty big monitor, so I do not want to end these lines so early. Could I somehow turn it off in Settings? I am using FormatOnSave and it is pretty anoying.

Thank you for all answers :))

Andrew

Comment: Hey, I formatted your post to be a bit more readable. By indenting your code or using backticks (`) it'll show up as code, highlighted an all

Comment: ... don't use `FormatOnSave`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're the following two settings in VS Code:

`"editor.wordWrap":`  Controls how lines should wrap.

`"editor.wordWrapColumn":` Controls the wrapping column of the editor when #editor.wordWrap# is wordWrapColumn or bounded.

So there're two solutions to your question, writing it in Settings.json:

1. Turn off the wordWrap:

   ```
    "editor.wordWrap":"off",
   ```
2. Still keep wordWrap on but changing the code's max-length:

   ```
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn":130,
   ```

Comment: Oh, I only tried to set Wordwrap column to the highest value. That did nothing, but when I turned it off, is seems to work. If I want any extension that can format your code while saving it, does for example prettier do the same job?

Comment: I don't know your highest value, but default wordwrap column is 80, while your code length is much more than 80, so turn off wordwrap can achieve your goal. The prettier can also provide this function, you can refer to [the official docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html),.